# Resolving connection strings with a static cache

Tags: c#

All requests must be validated whether the given site URL exists in a database. If it exists, the connection string will be built based on a given URL and an SQL connection will be opened. I created a static cache for these URLs (key: site URL, value: database name) because I don't want to query the database every time I need to build a connection string for a specific URL. When a connection string is successfully created, an API controller checks if any car is available.

Controller

```
public class CarController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Available(SiteUrl model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var conStr = ResolveClientConnectrionString(model.Url);
            if (conStr != "")
            {
                return Ok(CarHelper.CheckIfAnyAvailable(conStr));
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    private static string ResolveClientConnectrionString(string url)
    {
        if (CarHelper.DBs.ContainsKey(url))
        {
            var clientConnectionString = GetConnectionStringForDatabaseName(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString, CarHelper.DBs[url]);

            return clientConnectionString;
        }
        else
        {
            var databaseName = "";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                var query = "Select Top(1) url, dbName from sites where url=@url";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", url);
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            databaseName = (string)rdr["dbName"];

                            if (databaseName != "")
                            {
                                CarHelper.DBs.Add((string)rdr["url"], (string)rdr["dbName"]);

                                var clientConnectionString = GetConnectionStringForDatabaseName(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString, databaseName);

                                return clientConnectionString;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }
    }

    private static string GetConnectionStringForDatabaseName(string mainConnectionString, string databaseName)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(mainConnectionString)
        {
            InitialCatalog = databaseName
        };
        var clientConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
        return clientConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Static helper class

```
public static class CarHelper
    {
        // key: url | value: database name
        public static Dictionary<string, string> DBs { get; set; }

        static CarHelper()
        {
            DBs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                var query = "select url, dbName from Sites";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            if (!DBs.ContainsKey((string)rdr["url"]))
                            {
                                DBs.Add((string)rdr["url"], (string)rdr["dbName"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static Car CheckIfAnyAvailable(string connectionString)
        {
            var result = new Car();

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                string query = @"Select TOP 1 Id, Name from Cars where Available=@available";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@available", true);
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            result.Id = (long)rdr["Id"];
                            result.Name = (string)rdr["Name"];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Available()` you may want to reduce indentation to make it easier to read. I'd also consider to return an appropriate code when URL isn't found in DB (it might make client debugging easier).

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);

var connectionString = ResolveClientConnectionString(model.Url);
if (conStr == "")
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

return Ok(CarHelper.CheckIfAnyAvailable(connectionString));
```

`ResolveClientConnectrionString()`. `"MainConnectionString"` is repeated three times in your code. Move it to a `private` (or `internal`) `const string` field.

In this SQL code:

```sql
Select Top(1) url, dbName from sites where url=@url
```

You do not actually need `url` in returned dataset, just drop it. Also I'd suggest to use consistent casing for SQL commands (and to move it to a `const string` field, at least until you won't need more logic and you will introduce a separate class for that).

```
private const string SqlQueryDbNameByUrl
    = "SELECT TOP(1) dbName FROM sites WHERE url=@url";
```

This snippet is small and simple but in general when using `AddWithValue()` you should be careful, I'd suggest to get used to...don't use it at all (so you won't need to think when it's *safe* and when it's not).

You do not need to declare `databaseName` before its usage:

```
string databaseName = reader.GetString(0);
if (databaseName == "")
    return "";

CarHelper.DBs.Add(url, databaseName);
return GetConnectionStringForDatabaseName(MainConnectionString, databaseName);
```

**Cache**. It's just broken, ASP.NET is multi-threaded and `Dictionary<string, string>` is not thread-safe and to read everything in ctor is pretty inefficient (unless you have just few entries, it's not really the purpose of a cache). You may use a thread-safe dictionary, you may lock it, you may use an in-memory database (!!!) or simply...make your life easy and reuse existing cache classes like `MemoryCache`. One note about existing code (which I'd simply drop): `CarHelper` should not be `public` and I see no reason for `DBs` to have a public setter. In this moment responsibility to *manage* this *cache* is shared between its users and `CarHelper` class. If you want a cache then abstract it:

```
static MyCacheIShouldNotUse
{
    public static string Get(string name, Func<string, string> factory)
    {
        lock (_data)
        {
            if (_data.TryGetValue(name, out string value))
                return value;

            var newValue = factory(name);
            _data.Add(name, newValue );

            return newValue;         
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, string> _data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Given this proof of concept then `factory` can be dropped in favor of a `static private` method (in your cache if it's specialized or in a separate class where you manage DB access).

Now you might want to **test** the cache and static methods aren't the best for this. Let's make them instance methods and eventually provide a singleton (compromise...) instance like `MyCacheIShouldNotUse.Default`.

Too much work, right? `MemoryCache` is already there (and it will nicely also handle expiration policies).

---

Side note: I don't see your full code then I'm just guessing but usually to store URL in database (are you using them to identify the car?!) is not a great idea. URLs are mutable and parsing URL might be better (you're already using ASP.NET MVC, after all).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need URL to identify from which site request came, because there are separated database per client. Unfortunately I cannot change this behaviour, I can only refactor them. I initialize cache in ctor because there will be only several dozen entries (it's better to query database only once after application start, right?). Caching these URLs are important for me, because api will receive a few hundred requests per minute and I need check URL every time. For this small purpose maybe it's better to use only ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: In further (another project) I want to implement generic cache for storing various objects, what do you think about this implementation of MemoryCache? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756423/How-to-Cache-Objects-Simply-using-System-Runtime-C

Comment: If you use it as an in-memory DB then forget about concurrency, multiple concurrent reads are safe (but you might consider expiration...) Do you need another implementation? .NET already has one in `System.Runtime.Caching`